# Can i declare class or member using keyword default?

Tags: java, keyword

Can I declare a class default using the keyword *default*? For example:

```
default class Test{

}
```

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: and what did you expect this to do?

Comment: So why exist the keyword default?

Comment: what was the message for that error you mention?

Comment: Pai.java:5: class, interface, or enum expected
default class Test{
^
1 error

Comment: Default is used in switch statements.

Comment: @AndyBursh:  It's also used in annotations as well.

Comment: @Makoto Didn't know that! Learn something new every day :)

Comment: in Java 8 `default` also used in order to define method in interface [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no access modifier called as `default`, if you don't specify any modifier for class or method, implicitly, they default to package private.

But, Java has a `default` keyword, which is used in `switch` `case` statements. If the supplied option not in any case, and if you specified the default behavior then that will be used.

For example,

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

Here, if you gave any invalid month, then it will be fall in the default section.

Comment: The sentence `There is no access modifier called as default` is not valid now. Java8 allows us to define methods in interface with default  modifier. they are also called `virtual extension methods` or `defender methods`

Comment: `default` keyword is used in annotations.

Comment: and now in interfaces as well, see `Collection`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new feature came with java 8, using default keyword we can define methods in interfaces.

```
interface I {
   public default void show() {
     System.out.println("Hello");
   }
}
```

Described in Java 8 [JLS-13.5.6. Interface Method Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.5.6)

> Adding a default method, or changing a method from abstract to default, does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries, but may cause an IncompatibleClassChangeError if a pre-existing binary attempts to invoke the method. This error occurs if the qualifying type, T, is a subtype of two interfaces, I and J, where both I and J declare a default method with the same signature and result, and neither I nor J is a subinterface of the other.

Comment: This is the simplest explanation of java default keyword that I've ever seen, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "if you don't specify any modifier for class or method, implicitly, they default to package private" is totally wrong. If a class is private then that class doesn't have access even within same package. But if we don't mention any access specifier, then the class will be taken as default which has access within the package.

Comment: While the name is not perfect, "package private" is just what you said.